# Good Language to Send Keystrokes to other programs

Tags: macros, send, keystrokes

What would be a good language to send keystrokes to third programs. Such as skype, emulators, and such. It can be a scripting language or an OOP language. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The following works in PowerShell:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Readme.txt - Notepad")

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("ABCDEFGHIJKLM")
```

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt - http://www.autoitscript.com/

AutoHotkey - http://www.autohotkey.com/

I personally prefer AutoIt because its not as cryptic but both are easy to learn and pretty powerful when it comes to creating macros.

Comment: Generally, try not to answer questions asking to find tools. I get that you wanted to answer this question, but link-only answers usually don't help, and even though this question was basically asking for exactly that, you shouldn't answer with a bunch of links only.